# Mailchimp total difference

Tags: mailchimp

I use mailchimp api in order to make custom reports, and I saw that there's a difference between what the api returns and what is displayed on Mailchimp reports dashboard.
Even on the dashboard, there's a difference. Here's an example of an unsubscribed report:

```
No longer interested 91
Did not sign up 48
Inappropriate content 0
Spam 2
Other 0
Unspecified 82
```

So total is 223. Same total from the api.

But when I export the unsubscribed report, I have only 195 rows.
Does someone know why there's such a difference?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The difference (e.g. 28 contacts) are hard bounces. They are unsubscribed and shown in total, but they were unsubscribed by system (because those mailboxes doesn't exist anymore) and not by themselves, so they don't fall to any reason.